# Program/ App: "Einstellungen", "Konfiguration", "Optionen" - difference?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology

What does "**Einstellungen**", "**Konfiguration**", "**Optionen**" mean in an app or program, what is the difference and where does it come from?

***Edit:*** Sorry, I wrote this question with my mobile after some disappointment with my dictionary yesterday evening. So I improve my question now:

## Starting point and question

A program/app is a unit of (mostly compiled) software that offers functionality to the user for a (*usually*) specific coherent scope of application (usage) ["usually": especially the word *app*(lication) stresses that - *program* tendentiously stresses the *predescribed process* - we mostly use those words equally *because due to order precepts* it is useful for a program/app to concentrate on one application area].

The program/app mostly has (multiple) main applications within that application area. E.g. a music program/app for the area of music playing which let's you control the main applications

1. **organize your titles** (search, albums organisation, playlist,...)
2. **play a title** (volume control, equalizer, fast-forward, ...)

[Note that in this example additionaly the main applications are not just connected by their similiar area of usage, but of the functionality itself: "playlist" e.g. is connected to 1) and 2)].

Running the main (sub)applications of that application (almost ever) results in variable states due to the sequence of the advancing process and due to variable/changeable decisions (the ifs,... in the programming language). The (last named) variance of the variable/changeable decisions is caused by:

- **no human** (not directly, in the end nearly everything is caused by human): E.g. a cover is loaded from the web using a cover site, because that cover was available, a track could not be found, because of the system environment on which the app is running,...
- **human** (in detail: that's what I'm interested in)

  - **in advance of starting** the main applications **to control how the main applications should work in my personal special subcase of the application area**: E.g. login into an music service account (better example: or setting parameters of an http server, e.g. how big the thread pool is),... .
  - **while the application is used** (interactive - the user is actively acting in between ("inter") the program sequence advances)

    - to **use** the **main applications interactivly**, e.g. to select an mp3 by tapping and so on
    - **to control how the main applications should work in my personal special subcase of the application area**, e.g. which bass amplifier I want to use

I'm particularly interested in the part **"to control how the main applications should work in my personal special subcase of the application area"**, which **can be set in advance** before starting the application **and** (if interactive) even **while the application is used** [for appps the first part doesn't really happen , so that "login example" is a bit problematic ]. **Sometimes** these "controls" are **necessary to be specified by the user** (e.g. login) and **sometimes** they **can be set with an standard value**.

These "*controls*" are what I'm interested in my question.

***Question:*** So **how does "Einstellungen", "Konfiguration", "Optionen" organize these "controls" terminological?**

## What I already found out

First:

1. **Programs use** those terms **partly interchangeably**.
2. The **german wiki uses those terms partly interchangeably** (["Konfiguration (Computer), der Aufbau und der Einstellungen (Optionen) beim Bau von Computern und der Administration von Software"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konfiguration) ).

**Result: No satisfying answer.**

**Going to wiktionary:**

- "*Optionen*" comes from "free will" and stresses the possibility of choice.
- "*Einstellungen*" Possibility to change the manner of behaviour of the program. It comes from "einstellen" (so maybe metaphorical, we place the parts as we want them - engl. "setting" fits here nice).
- "*Konfiguration*" form/shape (figure) together (con).  Setting from program parameters (says nothing else, then to change the manner of behaviour).

**Result**: So what do we have:
"Optionen" says, we have a choice.
"Einstellungen" says, shape/form we chose.
"Konfiguration" is similiar to "Einstellung", just latin.

***All three say*** imply we have a choice, and the *last two stress we coordinated our choice*. So in other words: The etymology I found, **isn't much helping here** (but maybe I'm wrong?).

That's why I was asking the question here.

## Responding to the proposal of advert2013 (first answer)

[As it seems appropriate I just add the term (operational) "**Parameter**" (plural). To me it seems to be that this term is the *(technical) equivalent* of my "controls" (control focuses on the user perspective). A single "control" is a single "parameter".]

- **Einstellungen**/ settings means the same as my "controls" (collection/class [in the sense of order] of parameters)

  - **Konfiguration/ configuration** is that subcase of controls, that are configured in advance of starting the application.
  - **Interactive "Einstellungen"/settings** is that subcase of controls, that can be configured after application starting.

(I'm good with that.)

**Options** are the concrete (alternative) values I can set for a specific parameter.

***Not completely satisfying***: With this last point I'm not satisfied, because I nearly never saw this used in that way in programs/apps. Any other ideas?

*Added question:* **Properties ("Merkmale"?)** and **preferences ("Präferenzen"?)** **are not used in german** concerning programs/apps?

(**Main order criteria for that "controls" until here are**: 1. time of controlling [while using the application or before]. Maybe we could add 2. necessity of user specifying [no standard value] or 3. impact [effecting only one subapplication or the whole application])

__

I subjectively think, that this question is quite interesting, because we use programs/apps frequently nowadays and this question wasn't raised yet in this community.

Comment: @userunknown Note my edit.

Comment: @userunknown I improved my post, anything else I can do now against that "on hold"?

Comment: Now it seems you found out in detail, what you were looking for. Now it's unclear, what you're asking.

Comment: @userunknown Answers which propose terminal taxonomies for that "controls" (with clear criteria).

Answer (score 4):

They're just the same as the distinctions made in English:

**Einstellungen = Settings**: General functions that alter the way the program operates.

**Optionen = Options**: The range of choices you have within an individual setting (e.g. black and white, colour, sepia).

**Konfiguration = Configuration**: Often used to refer to settings chosen during installation that alter the way the program operates, or determine what parts of the program are installed.

Comment: If only every software developer knew about these differences and would adhere to them …

Comment: @advert2013 I like your definition of "Einstellungen" and "Konfiguration". About "Optionen" I'm not sure, I don't remember any program using that. Do you have an argument, using that definition?
Do you know, if equivalents of "preference" and "properties" are used in german refering to programs/apps?

Comment: The only time I really see 'optionen' written in a program is with search options. Here's an example: http://static.giga.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Google-Erweiterte-Suche-Suchoptionen.jpg . Otherwise it's just a word used to describe the range of choices in a manual or whatever, while not normally being stated in the app itself (which will just state the setting – 'Farbe' or whatever). Preferences are just 'Einstellungen' I believe. No doubt they have all been used in totally different ways to the general outline I gave, but that looseness is just a feature of natural language in general.